# Showing there is no smooth structure such that the inclusion is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to do the following exericse :

> Let $A=\{(x,|x|):x\in \mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that there is no smooth structure on $A$ such that $i:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is an immersion.

Now trying to prove this I had two ideas, going by contradiction, one using the constant rank theorem and another using the differential itself, and in both of them I try to focus on the point $0$ since this seems this will be give some trouble due to the fact that we have the function $|x|$ in there.

So using the constant rank theorem we know that there will be local coordinates $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ such that $\psi\circ i\circ \phi^{-1}(x)=(x,0)$. With this I tried to use some homeomorphism argument between spaces to obtain a contradiction but got nowhere.

Now for the differential we know that for a point $p$, $d_pi(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=\sum_{j=1}^{2}\frac{\partial(i\circ \phi^{-1})^j}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$ , but I can't seem to know anything about those derivatives itself to obtain that this will not be injective .

So any hint or suggestion on how to prove this is aprecciated, just trying to know if I am going in the right direction . Thanks in advance.

New edit : Started thinking about this again , and now my idea is well since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can make the canonical identification of the tangent space and the differential will simply be derivative of the function $(x,|x|)$, and at $0$ we will have the problem that this is not an immersion . Intuitively this works for me , but it is not a rigorous way to prove the statement.

Comment: Not sure how to best phrase this as a hint, but you can do as follows: Pick a chart $\varphi$ containing $(0,0)$ and assume $\iota$ is smooth, so that $\iota\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is smooth. Show that the second component of $\iota\circ\varphi^{-1}$ has derivative $0$ at $\varphi(0,0)$ by looking at the difference quotient and then conclude the same holds for the first component by the nature of $A$. Then $\iota\circ\varphi^{-1}$ has zero differential at $\varphi(0,0)$, hence $\iota$ has zero differential at $(0,0)$ and isn't an immersion.